# What is a Difference between DevOps Interface from VS19 Debug Mode to published Website?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a web application which is published on a same PC where I do coding and debugging.
One of the functionalities is an interface to company's Azure DevOps server to read or write WorkItems.
I am working with VS19. If I am in debug mode started from VS (F5 or ctrl+F5), communication to DevOps is working great, I can read and write WorkItems. If I try to do same from published site with debug configuration, which is hosted on same PC, I get response, that my request is refused.

To test my connection state I implemented a small test connection method according to [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page)
Authentication is realized with PAT. PAT is correct and authentication is working.

```
public async Task<ConnectionStatus> CheckAzureConnection()
{
  string url = _uri + "/_apis/connectionData?api-version=5.1-preview";
  ConnectionStatus status = new ConnectionStatus();

  try
  {
  
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
        Convert.ToBase64String(
          System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
            string.Format("{0}:{1}", "My User Name", _personalAccessToken))));


      using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
      {
        status.Status = response.StatusCode.ToString(); 
        return status;
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    status.Status = "Not OK";
    return status;
  }
}
```

This code is working during debug, but not in published website. Site is published on IIS Webserver. An internal valid certificate is bound to site. IIS Basic authentication is switched of according to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/iis-basic-auth?view=azure-devops). Honestly, I tried to switch it on and off.

First site was published with release configuration, but actually because of issue I switched to debug configuration, without success to issue.

Do anyone have any ideas what I did forget? Why my request get declined?

Comment: Check if you are missing any configuration in the published app. For example, where are you getting the _personalAccessToken from? It might be the case that while debugging, you getting from UserSecret which is only available in debugging session. But when you deploy, it does not find in the config?

Comment: PAT is from database. I use same token in debug and published site. Connection to database is working on published site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was in IIS configuration. As I mentioned in my question, site is running in company network. I configured application pool to be executed by a local user. After I changed local user to a network user it worked.
As I know, VS has its own IIS and this is running with signed network user. This was a difference to IIS on host.